# PHP mail can not send when there is a url a tag in the body

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

When I added "a href tag " in the mail body the mail is not sent.

If I remove this 'a href and www' tag, the mail sends and all other content display as per my requirement.

I don't know where is the exact problem, I'm using GoDaddy hosting with PHP 5.3 version.

If anyone has a better solutions please share with me .

```
<?php
// multiple recipients

$to = 'ali.dzinemedia@gmail.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// message
$message = '<a href=www.google.com>Click here</a>';

// To send HTML `enter code here`mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <ali.dzinemedia@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <ali.dzinemedia@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

echo "To : ".$to;

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: I would recommend to use PHPMailer (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or Swiftmailer (http://swiftmailer.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this as the header:

```
 $header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset: utf8\r\n";
```

that's if you want to use HTML in the body, but you have to create well formatted HTML, you know with all of its tags: html, head, body, and close them all.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>Content here and <a href="#">this</a> is a link</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fine But when i replace a tag HREF # into my website URL : http://www.google.com . then mail not send.. i check the same script at my dedicated server its working perfectly on my another server dont know why it getting problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once, turned out my spam filter blocked the mail when a link was in it and let it trough when I removed the link.

Took me some time to notice that

Comment: check your spam folder :)

Comment: to bad, was worth a shot :)